# Как передать переменную в дочернее окно?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, pyqt6, qmainwindow

Помогите, пожалуйста, с решением данной задачи (суть максимально упростил).

Требуется следующее:

1. По кнопке в главном окне присваивается значение некоторой переменной и открывается второе окно.
2. Необходимо, чтобы у второго окна был доступ к этой переменной (в
   данном случае у закомментированной строки `print(a)`).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как передать переменную **`a`** из класса `Window()` в класс `Window_303()`?

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget


class Window_303(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        #print(a)


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.w = Window_303()
        button = QPushButton("Открыть окно", self)
        button.show()
        button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.button_actions())
        self.show()

    def button_actions(self):
        a = 2
        self.show_window_303(self)

    def show_window_303(self, checked):
        self.w.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Window()
    main_window.resize(200, 200)
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget
 
 
class Window_303(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, a, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        print(a)
 
 
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        button = QPushButton("Открыть окно", self)
        button.show()
        button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.button_actions())
        self.show()
 
    def button_actions(self):
        a = 2
        self.show_window_303(self, a)
 
    def show_window_303(self, checked, a):
        self.w = Window_303(a)
        self.w.show()
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Window()
    main_window.resize(200, 200)
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Структура главного окна `QMainWindow`**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Научитесь использовать [**менеджеры компоновки**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/layout.html):

---

Не используйте `lambda`, там где ее не надо использовать.

---

Поменяйте импорты и проверьте. Улучшенный вариант, выглядит так:

```
import sys
'''
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, \
    QPushButton, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window_303(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(300, 400)
        self.parent = parent
        
        self.label = QLabel(self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel {
                color: rgb(253, 253, 253); 
                background-color: #105652;
                font-size: 33px;
            }
        """)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)        

    def show_values_a(self):                              # !!! так будет правильнее
        print(f'values_a = {self.parent.values_a}')       #
        self.label.setText(self.parent.values_a)
        

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()                                         # +
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)                              # +
        
        self.values_a = None                                                   # +

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Введите значение для переменной values_a")

        self.button = QPushButton("Открыть окно", self)
# ?        button.show()
# ---------------------------------> vvvvvvv <----------------> vv <---------  ???
#        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.button_actions())
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_actions)
# ?        self.show()

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)                         # +
        main_layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)

        self.lineEdit.setFocus()
        
        self.window_303 = Window_303(self) 
        

    def button_actions(self):
#        a = 2
        self.values_a = self.lineEdit.text()                                  # +

#        self.show_window_303(self)
        self.show_window_303()

#    def show_window_303(self, checked):
    def show_window_303(self):
        self.window_303.show_values_a()                                   # !!! +++
        self.window_303.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):                                              # +         
        self.window_303.close()
        event.accept()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Window()
    main_window.resize(300, 200)
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]